# Prevent v-navigation-drawer from closing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-model

**Expected Behavior:** 
 **1.** On initial render, the component should auto open the corresponding v-list-item's subgroup. 
 **2.** Then, on clicking an adjacent subgroup item, the nav drawer should remain opened to the subgroup the user has click on.

**Problem:** 
 When performing **2**, the entire nav drawer will close rather than the expected behavior.

> I still need to keep the `:value` v-binds, but **I believe the problem has something to do with preventing the `#activator` from propagating v-on when clicking an item.**

**Oddity:** Any subsequent clicks on nav drawer items will result in normal behavior after experiencing the initial problem.

Any help would be appreciated if you've come across this problem before. Thank you!

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-group
          v-for="(subObjects, fruit) in items"
          :key="fruit"
          :value="fruit === 'orange'"
          no-action
        >
          <template #activator>
            <v-list-item-title>
              {{ fruit }}
            </v-list-item-title>
          </template>
          <template>
            <v-list-group
              v-for="object in subObjects"
              :key="object.name"
              :value="object.name === 'navel'"
              no-action
              sub-group
            >
              <template #activator>
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-title>
                    {{ object.name }}
                  </v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
              </template>
              <v-list-item
                v-for="year in object.dates"
                :key="year"
              >
                <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
                  <v-list-item-title v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                    {{ year }}
                  </v-list-item-title>
                </template>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list-group>
          </template>
        </v-list-group>
      </v-list>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<script> 
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: {
        apples: {
          0: {
            color: 'red',
            name: 'fuji',
            dates: ['2016', '2018'],
          },
          1: {
            color: 'green',
            name: 'granny smith',
            dates: ['2020', '2021'],
          }
        },
        oranges: {
          0: {
            color: 'orange',
            name: 'navel',
            dates: ['2022']
          },
          1: {
            color: 'red orange',
            name: 'blood orange',
            dates: ['2015', '2017'],
          }
        },
      }
    };
  },
};
</script>
```